# There's a SQL trace file being populated every day. How can I find the routine running the trace file populating it with data?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

So I found a strange folder inside my SQL Server. It's called Analysis and most of its files was not updated since 2015. but there are 2 trace files being updated daily. theres some useless information inside it ( only start date and end date of something ) and a TXT file with only errors. how can I find what is starting this trace ? can't find it under traces, or schedules taks on SO.

[image: These are the files. where is this coming from ??]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like those files are coming from the [Flight Recorder monitoring feature](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3616/sql-server-analysis-services-flight-recorder/) within SSAS.

To turn it off, connect to the Analysis Services server from SSMS, go to server properties, General tab, (you might need to select Show Advanced (All) Properties, and change the value under Log -> FlightRecorder -> Enabled to false.

Comment: Yes thank you I could find that it was SSAS that was using these files. I just disabled the service. We don't do that here.

Answer (score 0):

You need run the following query to check the objects creating a trace file across all databases.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(id) objectName,*
    FROM syscomments 
    WHERE text LIKE '%sp_trace_create%'
```

Once you have the objectname, you can search which job task is creating it.

```
SELECT * FROM msdb..sysjobs jobs
INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobsteps stp ON stp.job_id = jobs.job_id
WHERE command LIKE '%<objectname>%' 
   or command LIKE '%sp_trace_create%'
```

Or, just look for the job tasks that start at 12:40.

Comment: Yep, no results. Thanks Dan. There's no jobs about this because I created all of them. this is something from years before I got the work here.